# remove the first word in filename with linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a ton of files that I need to rename. The name is currently 'sink-foobar'. I would like to remove 'sink-'. There must be a way to do this with bash but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple :

```
rename 's/sink-//' *files
```

It's the Perl one, sometimes named `prename`, it's installed as default on Ubuntu and many distros.

To be sure you have the right one, run this command :

```
file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename)) | grep &>/dev/null -i perl &&
    echo "Good version" ||
        echo "ELF version, not the good one"
```

On Debian and derivated (Ubuntu...), you can set it as default with :

```
 update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/vendor_perl/rename
```

See https://metacpan.org/module/rename

Comment: Unless you have the other `rename`. Also, `foo-sink-bar`.

Comment: that didn't seem to have any effect

Comment: @Casey : try `prename 's/sink-//' *` Which distro do you use ?

Comment: See my edited post, test command added.

Comment: @sputnick That worked like a champ. Thank you sir! You are a God among men.

Answer (score 6):

Is it always a *literal* `sink-`? If so, use parameter expansion and strip prefix patterns:

```
NAME='sink-foobar'
echo ${NAME#sink-}
```

So, as a full script:

```
for f in sink-*; do
  mv -- "$f" "${f#sink-}";
done
```

Comment: With `nullglob` or `failglob` set, this is probably the perfect solution. Oh, if you want to remove a problem that will occur if a file is called `sink--hello` (or such, with 2 dashes), you'd better use `mv -- "$f" "${f#sink-}"`;